GitHub: Merge pull request manually, as automatic merging would overwrite important changes
I am working on a few feature branches of a repository on GitHub, and I want to update one of them to have the changes in another. More specifically, one branch replaces the current Lua interpreter (being used for DSP code) with LuaJIT, and the other updates a file format used elsewhere to make it more performant.
I have created a pull request to merge the LuaJIT branch into the file-format branch, and GitHub says there's no conflicts and the branches can be merged automatically, but actually looking at the changes, the LuaJIT version of the main file would completely overwrite the file format version, effectively removing the file format changes entirely.
For example, here's the block where the new format is read compared to what it would become.

In short, I want to choose how the changes are merged instead of letting Git decide. Is this possible? If so, how do I do it? If not, what options do I have? I still have some work left on the LuaJIT branch, so I'd rather have a solution I can use in the future as well, but if I have to create a new branch and copy all the file format changes over, so be it.

"I want to choose how the changes are merged instead of letting Git decide. Is this possible?" No. An automerge uses merge logic, which involves comparing the differences since the two branches diverged and implementing them both. The only way to change a branch to exactly what you want, using a pull request, is to make a new branch from it, set things up the way you want them, and make the PR and merge, at a time when the first branch has not advanced at all; that way, the first branch has not changed at all and makes no contribution to the merge.

On the other hand, I don't quite get what you're doing. If you are working on multiple feature branches on your own machine, you don't make a pull request to merge from one to the other. You don't even need to merge. It's your branch, just make a commit that makes the branch look the way you want.

Dang, I was hoping that wouldn't be the case. I guess I'll have to do it the tedious way ¯_(ツ)_/¯

I'm working on features for someone else's repository, they want to merge LuaJIT soon and the file format later, but I want to use both changes at the same time for my own use and for testing.

Well now I really don't get it. If this is entirely on your machine for your own use and testing, you really don't need a PR. You just do the merge directly on your own machine. And at that point, you are free to make the merge come out however you like.
